# Changing Permalinks. Old links don't work

Tags: permalinks

Currently I'm using this permalink structure: mywebsite.com/%postname%.html
I want to change it to: mywebsite.com/%category%/%postname%/

When I do this, new links works fine, but the problem is, links to old posts, like mywebsite.com/some-old-post.html does not redirect to mywebsite.com/post-category/some-old-post/

I've read that WordPress is supposed to figure the new URL out automatically when the slug (some-old-post) stays intact, but in my case, it just goes to a 404 page.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need a plugin that uses 301 redirects to steer old permalinks to the new ones. Just search for 301 in the WP plugin directory.

Comment: I don't think 301 is the solution. Because there are many categories. Such as:
Article 1: mywebsite.com/postname1.html
Article 2: mywebsite.com/postname2.html

New structure 1: mywebsite.com/mycategory1/postname1/
New structure 2: mywebsite.com/mycategory2/postname2/

It'd work if there was 1 category, but there are dozens of categories.

Comment: Obviously, you don't want to create 301 entries for all posts. You need a bulk redirect. Try [Change Permalink Helper](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/change-permalink-helper/). This will steer links to their new location based on the post slug.